# Looker measure to average over last 3 years

Tags: sql, looker, lookml

I am trying to create a measure (LookML) that gives the average of funding over a three year window.

A sample of my data looks like this:

| year | person | funding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Amy | 20,000 |
| 2022 | Josh | 15,000 |
| 2021 | Amy | 23,000 |
| 2021 | Josh | 11,000 |
| 2020 | Amy | 29,000 |
| 2020 | Josh | 10,000 |

I'd like the measure to produce resulting data like this:

| person | 3 year avg. funding |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 24,000 |
| Josh | 12,000 |

The user would be able to pick the 3 year window using a filter, so the real data is between 1975-2023. I've tried this (below) but it's not worked.

```
  measure: average_funding {
    type: average
    label: "Average funding"
    sql: CASE WHEN ${year} >= CURRENT_DATE() -3 THEN ${funding} ELSE NULL END;;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, i assume your table is called `my_table`, and the LookML view is named `my_view`. The derived table selects all columns from `my_table`.

The `person` dimension is defined based on the `person` column in the table.

The `average_funding` measure uses the `average` type and refers to the `funding` column in the table. The measure is filtered using the `filters` parameter, which applies a date range filter on the `year` dimension.

The date range filter is defined using Liquid syntax and the `date.add_years` function. It calculates the three-year window dynamically by subtracting 3 years from the current date `(date.add_years(-3))` and including all years up to the current date `(date.add_years(0))`.

By setting up the measure and filter as shown above, you should be able to calculate the three-year average funding based on the user's selected filter window.

For example LookML :

```
view: my_view {
  derived_table: {
    sql: SELECT * FROM my_table;;
  }

  dimension: person {
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}.person ;;
  }

  measure: average_funding {
    type: average
    label: "3-Year Average Funding"
    sql: ${funding} ;;
    filters: {
      field: year
      view: my_view
      dimension: year
      operators: [in]
      values: ["{% condition year %} {{ date.add_years(-3) }} {% endcondition %}" TO "{{ date.add_years(0) }}"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I get ```Expecting 'end_of_file', 'keyword', '{', '}', ']', 'comma', ':', got 'identifier' ```
 for this line:       ```values: ["{% condition year %} {{ date.add_years(-3) }} {% endcondition %}" TO "{{ date.add_years(0) }}"]```